# a.e. continuous to left continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a $\lambda$-a.e. continuous function. Is the following statement true?

> There exists another function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g$ is left continuous and $f = g$ $\lambda$-a.e.

If it is not, what are some conditions on $f$ for this to hold?

I came up with this while comparing Riemann-Stieltjes integral to Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.

Edit: What if $f$ is BV or NBV?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \sin(1/|x|)$ for $x \neq 0$. This is discontinuous at $x=0$ no matter how we define $f(0)$, but it is continuous everywhere else.If $g = f$ a.e. then $g=f$ a.e. in every interval, so in each interval of the form $[-1/(2n\pi), -1/(2(n+1)\pi)]$, $g$ must take on points arbitrarily close to $+1$ and $-1$. Therefore $\lim_{x \to 0^-}g(x)$ does not exist, so $g$ cannot be left-continuous at $x=0$. (For the same reason, it cannot be right-continuous at $x=0$.) I am not sure what minimal additional conditions would make the result true, so this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I think the main point in the example is that $f$ oscillates strongly at zero. So, one could try with functions of bounded variation. This can be reduced to monotonically increasing functions (whose points of discontinuity are countable), since each BV function is a difference of two increasing ones. EDIT: I just realized that for these functions the claim holds.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp BV is rather strong comparing to what is asked for. However, I have no better idea either...

Comment: isn't a NBV function already left continuous?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, it's strong. I agree. But what do you mean by NBV?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: op asked also for NBV instead of BV. In that context, I take it means normalized BV. I am not sure, therefore I have asked.